# Chinese Remainder Theorem - solving a modulo with big numbers

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

I have the calculation: $2^{31}\pmod {2925}$

It's for university and we should solve it like:

1. make prime partition
2. $2^{31}$ mod all prime partitions
3. Solve with Chinese Remainder Theorem.

I started with $2925 = 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 13$ , and found out that:
$$2^{31} \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$$
$$2^{31} \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$$
$$2^{31} \equiv 11 \pmod{13}$$
I made:
$$x \equiv 2 \pmod3$$
$$x \equiv 3 \pmod5$$
$$x \equiv 11 \pmod{13}$$

Then I tried CRT and got $x = -1237 + 195k$

If you simply calculate $2^{31}\pmod{ 2925}$ you get $1298$, which is in fact $-1237 + 195 \cdot 13$.

I don't know how to find out the $13$.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

**SOLVED!**
I took $3$ instead of $9$ and $5$ instead of $25$ after prime partition. For more infos please see comments. Thanks!

Comment: For CRT you need to use moduli $\,9,25,13,\,$ not $\,3,5,13\,$

Comment: Ah, so I need to  multiply the same primes.. like if I had 3*3*3 instead of 3*3 I had to take 27?

Comment: You want the lcm of the moduli to be $2925$ in order to get the result mod $2925$, and you want them pairwise coprime so you can apply CRT.

Comment: Okay I see & I'will try. Thank you !

Comment: Worked out perfectly, thank you :)

Comment: I'm stuck under a tree trunk! @Somebody please help!

Comment: $2^{31}=734182\cdot 2925+1298$

Answer (score 2):

For CRT you need to use moduli $9,25,13$ not $3,5,13$

You want the l.c.m. of the moduli to be $2925$ in order to get the result modulo $2925$, and you want them pairwise coprime so you can apply CRT.

Thanks to Bill Dubuque for the answer.